# Which jQuery element is referenced in append() and appendTo()'s return value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm aware that both return a `jQuery` **type**. What I'm trying to figure out is, **what does the return value reference?**

1. Does `$( "<p>Test</p>" ).appendTo( ".inner" );` return a reference to `$( "<p>Test</p>" )` or $`( ".inner" );`?
2. Does `$( ".inner" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );` return a reference to `$( "<p>Test</p>" )` or $`( ".inner" );`?

e.g., if I were to chain `.css("color", "red")` on the return, which would get the style?

Since I can't find an answer in the official documentation of [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) or [appendTo](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), hopefully this question will show up high in the Google search results. Despite how easy this is to "try it and see"<sup>TM</sup>, it would be even easier if the answer existed somewhere.

Comment: 'Since I can't find an answer in the official documentation' Really? It says 'Returns jQuery' quite clearly in the top right. In both cases they return the initial jQuery object.

Comment: `Ctrl-F`, 'return'

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan see my edit

Comment: It returns the initial jQuery object. So in your examples, `appendTo()` will return a jQuery object containing the `<p>` element you created and `append()` will return a jQuery object containing the collection of `.inner` elements.

Comment: Why would you need to assume? Just read the jQuery docs. It tells you

Comment: `console.log( /*$...*/ )` no? Also by just doing `x.append(y).hide()` or `x.appendTo(y).hide()` would make it pretty obvious who's instance is being returned.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm confused as to why you said this *after* my answer effectively implemented your suggestion. Someone removed this from my original question, but the only reason I asked it in the first place was to document the answer *somewhere* on the Internet.

Comment: It is already "somewhere on the internet": https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery "In API calls that return jQuery, the value returned will be the original jQuery object unless otherwise documented by that API."

Comment: Hopefully the way I've edited this question is better worded than it was originally.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see from this snippet, they both return the element on the left of the call. In other words, both `x.append(y)` and `x.appendTo(y)` returns a `jQuery` referencing `x`.

```js
$("#append").click(function () {
  $(`.inner`).append(`<p class='test'>Test</p>`).css(`color`, `red`);
});

$("#appendTo").click(function () {
  $(`<p class='test'>Test</p>`).appendTo(`.inner`).css(`color`, `red`);
});

$("#reset").click(function () {
  $(".test").remove();
  $("*[style]").removeAttr("style")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello (class="inner")</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye (class="inner")</div>
</div>
<input id="append" type=button value="$(`.inner`).append(`<p class='test'>Test</p>`).css(`color`, `red`);"></input><br>
<input id="appendTo" type=button value="$(`<p class='test'>Test</p>`).appendTo(`.inner`).css(`color`, `red`);"></input><br>
<input id="reset" type=button value="Reset"></input>
```